# how we can enable and disable required field attribute from back end using PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, required

i have a option in my plugin that make  this field required or not but how we can manage please any one give me some solution i have try but fail

```
<div class="create-account">
        <p>
            <label for="label_birthday"><?php echo esc_attr( $birthday_label, 'dobc' ); ?>
            <?php if ( 'yes' === $birthday_required ) : ?>
                <span class="required" style="color:red;">*</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </label>
        <input type="date" class="input-text" name="dobc_date_field" id="date of birthd " value="<?php echo esc_html( $show_date ); ?>"  required/>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'birthday_nonce_action_checkout', 'birday_fields_checkout_nonce' ); ?>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna just html required attribute you can do something like this.

```
<?php $required =  ($birthday_required == 'yes') ? 'required' : '' ; ?>
<input name="dobc_date_field" <?php echo $required; ?> />
```